# Subscribe to Change event for all checkboxes with a certain string in their id

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I want to subscribe to change event for all checkboxes in a DataList control on an ASP.Net page.

I am able to get all these checkboxes by using the jQuery below, but I cannot find a way to subscribe to change event. **How would I do this using my jQuery below?**

```
$("input[id*='cbxColumn']").each(function (index, cbx) {

    cbx.onchange = " toggleSearch()";

});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a function called .bind() which is perfect for this application! Try something this:

```
$("input[id*='cbxColumn']").each(function (index, cbx) {

    $(cbx).bind("change", function(){ toggleSearch(); });

});
```

For more info check out this link: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

**or a more simple example using the .change() function:**

```
$("input[id*='cbxColumn']").each(function (index, cbx) {

    $(cbx).change(function(){ alert(); });

});
```

more info on this: http://api.jquery.com/change/